# Is it possible to keep localStorage items private or hidden?

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I want to keep someone from doing -

`localStorage[key]` in the console or similar to look at what I have there.

Is this possible to do?

Comment: Probably not. You're saving data to the user's computer, it's their right to be able to know what it is.

Comment: You could encrypt it using an encryption library http://crypto.stanford.edu/sjcl/. The question is what is this value used for? or rather how will it be used?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, that's not possible.

Such a feature would be pointless, because it would be easy to put a breakpoint in your code and look at the value after you have read it from the local storage.

You can scramble the value that you put in the storage so that it's not obvious what it means, but as the code that uses it is visible, you can only make it harder to see the value, not impossible.

Comment: ....localStorage has more exposure in that it always there, not just while the code is executing.  Your first statement is not correct....it would in fact have a point...privacy is a default state when writing OO code.  I was just wanting to apply that to persistent data as well.

Comment: @pure_code: In Javascript you can only create privacy from other code, the user can still see anything.

Comment: I'm cross-concepting....I mean even things like HTML/CSS for sites should by default be kept private, even though in practice it is the opposite, and seems to currently be un-supported.

Comment: @pure_code: That could be nice, but with the current protocols it's just no point in making the code protected, as you can easily request it using other tools than a browser.